# Android HERE SDK - sample app is not replacing app_id and app_code

Tags: android, here-api

I am trying to run the sample application according to the starter guide: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/app-run-simple.html

My problem is that, the requested URLs don't contain the appropriate `app_id` and `app_code`, as they exist in the manifest:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid" android:value="asdfghjklp098" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken" android:value="123poiiuyttrrwq" />
```

When I try to read the manifest values in code, using the following:

```
       try {
        ApplicationInfo app = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        Bundle bundle = app.metaData;
        Log.d("MetaDataLog", bundle.getString("com.here.android.maps.appid"));
          //prints asdfghjklp098
        Log.d("MetaDataLog", bundle.getString("com.here.android.maps.apptoken"));
         //prints 123poiiuyttrrwq
       } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

**The manifest meta-data is loaded correctly.**
The tile URLs request look like this:

```
E/a.a.a.a.a.z0$d: IOException : while creating server connection. | failed to connect to 2.base.maps.api.here.com/2.18.232.228 (port 443) from /10.0.2.16 (port 55900) after 5000ms for URL: https://2.base.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/11/324/701/512/png8?app_id={APP_ID}&app_code={APP_CODE}&lg=ENG&lg2=def&pview=DEF&ppi=320
```

Any **idea** what could be the issue ?

Comment: It looks ok from a declaration perspective. Did you add the license key too? Maybe there is a build issue that prevented the app to be updated?

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos where do I get the `license key?` I have a `freemium` account type. I searched the `zip` of the SDK, but haven't found it?

Comment: License key is displayed in the developer portal, when you generate credentials for "Android SDK Premium".

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue. The problem was, I was running on emulator.

I tested on another physical device, and the app was running fine.

Tip: **DO NOT use emulators, even if the documentation states that they are supported**. https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/system-requirements.html